# Cannot display response of HTML servlet in Ajax and qTip2

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am trying to display text (or html) that is received from a servlet response  in a qTip2 tooltip within a jsp. I have almost everything working and have verified with Firebug that the servlet is being invoked and text is being returned, but when I try to use the 'html' (or data) variable in my ajax call, I get an error: *HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy.*

I've tried displaying the html in a JavaScript alert, and this is what displays: [object XMLDocument].

Here is the sequence of events:

1.User clicks on a section of HTML text, which has a link defined that points to the servlet and passes parameters

2.The ajax invokes the servlet which does some processing and returns text or html

3.The text is displayed as a tooltip with qTip2

How can I properly handle the response from the servlet and manipulate the text that is received from it?

**Ajax call:**

```
$(".ajax_link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var link = $(this).attr('href'); //Gets link url

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: link,
        cache: false,

    }).done(function(html) {

        $this.qtip({
            content: {
                text: html //<--this causes error above
              //text: "<table><tr><th>Team</th></tr></table>"  <--this works fine
            }
        });

        $this.qtip('toggle', true);

    });
});
```

**Servlet Code:**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("inside doGet");

    String var1 = "<table><tr><th>Team</th></tr></table>";

    //var1 = request.getParameter("var1");

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(var1);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass dataType as html in ajax request
i.e.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: link,
        cache: false,
        dataType : "html"

    }
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! I tried that at one point before but maybe I had the wrong combination of other settings.